# How to compile gdal3.3.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, gdal, proj

I am working on compiling gdal for iOS. I can compile gdal1.11.5 via [this script:](https://gist.github.com/lachlanhurst/745e1e1d196c3e697450) (you should change the gdal version in the script) , I cannot compile gdal3.3.1.

Anyone can give me some suggestion?

```
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp -std=c++11
configure: error: in `/Users/xxx/Desktop/gdal05/proj-8.1.0':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp -std=c++11" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

**config.log**

```
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:3299: $? = 0
configure:3288: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3299: $? = 1
configure:3288: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:3299: $? = 1
configure:3319: checking whether the C compiler works


InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
configure:4323: $? = 0
configure:4312: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:4323: $? = 1
configure:4312: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files
configure:4323: $? = 1
configure:4327: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler

conftest.cpp:22:2: error: "This is not a C++11 compiler"
#error "This is not a C++11 compiler"
 ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
configure:4878: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
```

Comment: This is gdal version: http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/

Comment: This is proj version: http://download.osgeo.org/proj/

Comment: This is the script: https://gist.github.com/lachlanhurst/745e1e1d196c3e697450

Comment: This is the gdal introduction: https://gdal.org/download.html#binaries